# How to access JSF templates, classes of one maven module from another maven module

Tags: java, jsf, maven, web-applications

I have a Maven project which consists of 2 Maven modules.
One module has some common UI functionality which the Other module can reuse.
The common UI module has its own classes,dependencies,JSF templates 
and organized as per maven webapp structure.
It doesn't work if we add the common module in the dependency of calling module.
How can we call the Templates and related classes from the Other maven module?

Answer (score 2):

For classes simply use maven dependency with jar.

For web resources (jsf templates etc) use [maven overlay](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html) and merge resources from modules into one war module.

> > Overlays are used to share common resources across multiple web applications.

It is good practice to separete shared part of code (classes and webresources) into separate module (jar for classes and war for base war)